# How do I enable fast forward from branch to master

Tags: git

First of all - I know very little about git so I have looked at other maybe similar posts but I don't know if they are what I need.  And I know enough to know that if I run commands without being certain - things can go from bad to worse.

I have a branch (staging) and I use bitbucket to merge said branch into master.  It would support fast forward merging.

I thought I would be clever and try and run the merge from the command line so I wouldn't have to open bitbucket.

So from the command line I did the follow

```
git checkout master
git merge staging
```

Seemed to work. I then pushed it to bitbucket.

But after this all attempts to use my old technique now require me to select regular merge vs using fast forward.

This was all set up by someone else and now I don't how to fix this.

If I have master and staging.

And I want to reliably merge staging into master and retain history etc - do I need to go through the whole bitbucket path? What do I gain or lose?

Edit: Forgot to add that I also accidentally checked into master directly once.  Went back to checking into staging but I think that's the root of my problem.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/git-fast-forwards-and-branch-management-329977726.html and https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/merge-a-pull-request-945541513.html#Mergeapullrequest-Mergestrategies might help.

Comment: Thanks @Schwern.  I also forgot that I had made a mistake of merging into master instead of staging once.  So I looked at rebasing but I dont know how to do that.  I dont know which direction rebasing goes.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure fast forward merging you need to ensure that your staging branch is created from your master branch.

`git checkout master` - goes to the master branch.

`git checkout -b staging`  if staging does NOT exist. goes to staging.

`git checkout staging` if the staging branch DOES exist. Goes to staging.

Then you need to make sure that all the commits you add to master are also added to staging - i.e. if you make a bug fix on master  then you gotta have that same commit applied to the staging branch.

Or you have to ensure that you don't add any more commits to master while you work on staging. This is not always practical.  Now when you merge you'll get a fast forward which should not have any merge conflicts:

`git checkout master`

`git merge staging`

SUMMARY: You can't avoid merge conflicts when dealing with git. The easiest solution is to handle those conflicts when they arise and minimise the difficulties associated with dealing with them.  Commit early and often,  and merge as often as practicable to minimise headaches.

Comment: thanks.  I tried git checkout -b staging but it said that the branch already existed. I then tried the last two commands but it didn't resolve it. not sure what you mean by this "Then you need to make sure that all the commits you add to master are also added to staging"

Comment: I've added further comments.  Side note: You can't avoid merge conflicts all the time.  The best policy is to commit and merge often to minimise such conflicts.

Comment: Thanks. How does someone do this "Then you need to make sure that all the commits you add to master are also added to staging".  I tried to merge from master to staging but it said it was already up to date.

Comment: If it's up to date then you have nothing to worry about. If you make a change to master which is not in staging then you have to apply those changes to staging somehow: simplest way is by merging master into staging: but then you will have to deal with conflicts which may arise.  SUMMARY: it's impossible to avoid conflicts,  but very easy to deal with them.  It only takes 5 minutes to learn/ practice.  You can spin up a test git directory and experiment - that's the best way